# Clojure-tagged literals::Raise an error-No dispatch macro for it

Tags: clojure, literals

### tmp2/src/data_readers.clj

```
{ct/G tmp2.core/foo}
```

### tmp2/src/tmp2/core.clj

```
(ns tmp2.core)

(defn foo
  [x]
  (println x "Hello, World!"))

(defn -main
  [& args]

  (println "Hello, World!")
  (foo 123)
  (#ct/G "abc"))
```

When "lein run" in the project directory, it show the result "abc Hello, World!", but raise an error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No dispatch macro for: c
        at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:221)
        at clojure.lang.LispReader$DispatchReader.invoke(LispReader.java:851)
        at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:285)
        at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1398)
        at clojure.lang.LispReader$ListReader.invoke(LispReader.java:1243)
        at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:285)
        at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1398)
        at clojure.lang.LispReader$ListReader.invoke(LispReader.java:1243)
        at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:285)
        at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:216)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7630)
```

Where should I change the code? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fact, there are two problems here:

1) your `foo` function returns `nil`, and it appears that the reader function can't return literal nil. So you have to actually return something from `foo`:

```
(defn foo [x]
  (println x "Hello, World!")
  :something)
```

or, in case you really need `nil` in generated code, you can do this:

```
(defn foo [x]
  (println x "Hello, World!")
  '(quote nil))
```

2) the second problem  is that you actually try to call the result of your tag application here:

`(#ct/G "abc")`

the syntax `#tag value` is evaluated at read-time with `(tag-fn value)`, and then the result is literally put into the source code. when you use the extra pair of parens, that is what happens in your case:

`((foo "abc"))` and, as the `foo` function return `foo-return-value`, it is then left to be `(foo-return-value)` , and this, in turn, leads to an error.

so,

```
(defn foo [x]
  (println x "Hello, World!")
  :nothing)

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!")
  (foo 123)
  #ct/G "abc")
```

should probably work

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it working.

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn foo
  [x]
  (println :foo-reader x)
  x)

(dotest
  (println :test-foo-plain)
  (foo 123)
  (println :test-foo-reader)
  (println #ct/G "abc")
  (println :test-leave))
```

Note the location and contents of the Data Readers file.  It must be at the ROOT of the classpath. In this case that is `src/clj`:

```
~/expr/demo > cat src/clj/data_readers.clj
{ct/G tst.demo.core/foo}
```

and test results:

```
> lein test

:foo-reader abc    ; <====== NOTICE!

-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 14
-------------------------------

:test-foo-plain
:foo-reader 123
:test-foo-reader
abc
:test-leave
```

Notice that the `foo` reader for the tagged literal was invoked when the source code file was read, before it was compiled or the test was executed.

---

**Regarding the root of the classpath**

This is controlled for Lein projects by these entries in `projects.clj`:

```
  :source-paths            ["src/clj"]
  :java-source-paths       ["src/java"]
  :test-paths              ["test/clj"]
```

If you don't have the `clj` and `java` bits (some projects also segment `cljc` and `cljs` files into separate directory trees as well), you will need to modify either `project.clj` or the file location.

Comment: Thanks. Learn a lot from your answer.